# iOS 8.0.2 : UIView frame animation not working when UINavigationController contained inside RootViewController

Tags: objective-c, animation, uikit, ios8

I've created a RootViewController / RootView that:

- Handles the content layout for the app
- Exposes and interface for performing application level behaviors, like presenting the "hamburger" menu or overlay views with CAKeyframe animations.

This is in accordance with good practice.

**The Problem:**

When the main content view presents a form, there's a utility to animate the frame of that view, when a field is selected that would otherwise be obscured by the keyboard. This has been working fine all the way up until iOS 8.0.2

- On iOS 8.0.2 the frame for the form will no longer animate if you set a negative value for origin.y. Instead of going from the current origin.y to the required origin.y it jerks down by the amount it was supposed to move, then animates back to 0.
- If I present the form outside of the RootVC it works correctly.

**What I've tried:**

- Checked that RootView is not doing anything in layout subviews to prevent the animation. (In iOS8.0 it was. I removed this and problem was solved. Only to return in iOS8.0.2)
- Checked the BeginFromCurrentState flags.
- Instead of animating the form view, animate `[UIScreen mainScreen].keyWindow`. Works but causes some other side effects that I don't want.

**Question:**

What has changed with animation of UIViewControllers that are contained in another view in iOS8.0.2. It seems to be something very fundamental.

[image: RootVC]

**The code that animates frame to move input fields out the keyboard's way:**

Looks something like this:

```
- (void)scrollToAccommodateField:(UIView *)view
{
    UIView *rootView = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view;
    CGPoint position = [view convertPoint:view.bounds.origin toView:rootView];

    CGFloat y = position.y;
    CGFloat scrollAmount = 0;
    CGFloat margin = 25;
    CGSize screenSize = [self screenSizeWithOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation];
    CGSize accessorySize = CGSizeMake(_view.width, 44);

    CGFloat maxVisibleY = screenSize.height - [self keyboardSize].height - accessorySize.height - margin;

    if (y > maxVisibleY)
    {
        scrollAmount = maxVisibleY - y;
        CGFloat scrollDelta = scrollAmount - _currentScrollAmount;
        _currentScrollAmount = scrollAmount;
        [self scrollByAmount:scrollDelta];
    }
    else
    {
        if (_currentScrollAmount != 0)
        {
            _currentScrollAmount = 0;
            [UIView transitionWithView:_view duration:0.30
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^
                {
                    _view.frame = [_view bounds];
                } completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I've since installed [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) pod and its working very well. . leaving this open, in case its of interest to others.